# Colocar tabuada em PHP em tabela HTML

Tags: php, html, funções, table

Estou tentando colocar a função de uma tabuada que fiz em PHP em uma tabela HTML, mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me dar um forcinha?

```
 <?php
function tabuada($tabuada){
   $cont = 1;

   while ($cont <= 10){
      $resultado = $tabuada * $cont;
      echo ($tabuada."x".$cont." = ".$resultado)."<br>";
      $cont++;
   }
}

$tabela = '<center><table border="1";>';
$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td>tabuada (10)</td>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
$tabela .= '</table></center>';
echo $tabela;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que da maneira que você chamou a função `tabuada`, ela está sendo interpretada como uma string:

```
$tabela .= '<td>tabuada (10)</td>';
```

Como sua função `tabuada` já faz a impressão utilizando `echo`, bastaria chamá-la para que a tabuada seja exibida:

```
tabuada(10);
```

Porém isso claro, ficaria longe de ser impresso dentro da `table`.

---

Para que a tabuada seja impressa dentro da table, sua função `tabuada` precisa ser alterada e o restante do código também... Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, abaixo um exemplo tentando manter o seu código:

```
<?php

function tabuada($tabuada){
   $cont = 1;
   $resultado = '';

   while ($cont <= 10){
        $resultado .= '<tr><td>' . $tabuada . 'x' . $cont . ' = ' . ($tabuada * $cont) . '</td></tr>';
      $cont++;
   }

   return $resultado;
}

$tabela .= '<center><table border="1";>';
$tabela .= tabuada(10);
$tabela .= '</table></center>';

echo $tabela;

?>
```

Agora sua função `tabuada` retorna uma string, contendo a tabuada já dentro das tags `tr` e `td`, com isso passamos a criar a invocar a função `tabuada` e concatenar o seu retorno no restante do código que gera a `table`.

Comment: O elemento [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) é obsoleto.